Apply pose bone location and None inherit scale to local bone location and Full inherit scale
How can I transform pose bone's transforms from (what I assume is) pose space to local space and also get rid of use_local_location = False and inherit_scale = "NONE"? These 2 bone properties have to be initially set in order for animation to get imported correctly, however they're not attached to imported action, so applying this action on another Armature without setting these properties makes it look wrong. Here's the script function I use to apply transforms:
def apply_track_transforms_to_posebone(
        pose_bone: bpy.types.PoseBone,
        transforms: list[(tuple[float, float, float] | None, Quaternion | None, Vector | None)],
        ignore_origin_location: bool,
):
    """
    Applies track transforms to PoseBone for every keyframe of animation.
    :param pose_bone: Target PoseBone.
    :param transforms: List of (Location, Rotation, Scaling) track transform tuples.
    :param ignore_origin_location: Whether to ignore location transforms from Origin track.
    """
    pose_bone.bone.use_local_location = False
    if hasattr(pose_bone.bone, "inherit_scale"):
        pose_bone.bone.inherit_scale = "NONE"
    if hasattr(pose_bone.bone, "use_inherit_scale"):
        pose_bone.bone.use_inherit_scale = False
    matrix = pose_bone.bone.matrix_local
    if pose_bone.parent:
        matrix = pose_bone.parent.bone.matrix_local.inverted() @ matrix
    loc, rot, _ = matrix.decompose()
    for i, transform in enumerate(transforms):
        has_location = False
        has_rotation = False
        has_scale = False
        if transform[0] is not None:
            loc_x = transform[0][0] - loc[0]
            loc_y = transform[0][1] - loc[1]
            loc_z = transform[0][2] - loc[2]
            if not ignore_origin_location or pose_bone.bone.name.casefold() != "Origin".casefold():
                pose_bone.location = Vector((loc_x, loc_y, loc_z))
            has_location = True
        if transform[1] is not None:
            pose_bone.rotation_quaternion = rot.conjugated() @ transform[1]
            has_rotation = True
        if transform[2] is not None:
            pose_bone.scale = Vector(transform[2])
            has_scale = True
        if has_location:
            pose_bone.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=i)
        if has_rotation:
            pose_bone.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_quaternion", frame=i)
        if has_scale:
            pose_bone.keyframe_insert(data_path="scale", frame=i)

